# Accessing Orchard CMS settings programatically inside a Module

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I am writing an Orchard CMS module within a multi-tenant application.

I would like to be able to access the settings declared when the tenant was set up, namely the DB table prefix which i'd like to use as a unique identifier for the current tenant in other areas of my system.

Is there an API/Helper I can query for these settings?

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the site item from the work context. It has all the settings as parts. For the table prefix specifically it's a little different: you need to inject ShellSettings. But I would question the need to do that first...

Comment: thanks for that - can i just ask why you'd question the need to do that?  It's crucial that the table prefixes are unique in my app so seems like a nice readable identifier for the tenant.

Comment: Because there are very, very few scenarios where you need it. Needing it is a smell actually.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this, if it helps:

```
    private readonly ISiteService _siteService;
    public MyController(ISiteService siteService)
    {
        _siteService = siteService;
    }

    public void MethodExample(){
        var myVar = _siteService.GetSiteSettings().BaseUrl;
    }
```